# Как получить ширину и высоту блока текста, зная размер шрифта и где находятся переносы строки?

Tags: javascript, excel

Вот есть текст

"Основные ключевые \nпоказатели деятельности ОАО «КОЛОС»\nпо элементам"

Размер шрифта 12pt.
Можно ли зная эти данные получить ширину и высоту блока текста?

Еще известные значения.
Жирность bold.
Шрифт Arial.
Паддингов, отступов и границы нет.

Это нужно для расчёта высоты ячейки excel.

Comment: Размер блока будет зависеть не только от размера шрифта и переноса. А также от: шрифта, жирности, положения блока на странице, паддингов, бордеров. Для более точного ответа приведите пример `html` разметки и зачем вам это надо.

Comment: Это нужно для расчёта высоты excel ячейки.
Вопрос обновил, добавив те переменные которые известны.
Не обязательно точный алгоритм, главное чтобы высота примерно соответствовала и не обрезала текста.

Comment: Гммм... Если честно, немного смущает excel. Вы пытаетесь это сделать в google таблицы?